# Not working Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using comboBox Plugin.When i choose zawgyi-one in dropdown listbox, jquery not working.Why?

**html**

```
<div class="result">
    <span>မြန်မာစာ(Myanmar Text)</span>
</div>

<!-- For Testing Jquery -->
<button id="click-btn">Jquery Testing Button</button>
```

**javascript**

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#click-btn").click(function (){
        alert("jquery Work");
     });
  });
});
```

**[DMEO LINK is http://jsfiddle.net/qq6uq7c6/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/qq6uq7c6/12/)**

Comment: please provide code for your combobox plugin

Comment: I linked this plugin to external resources at DEMO.

Comment: Plugin Link http://yourjavascript.com/10122184592/font-convert.js

Comment: Alert working, if you not touch dropdown. but once you select anything from dropdown, after that alert not working

Comment: Yes, I can't solve this problem

Comment: You need to include jQuery in your page.

Comment: Yes,I linked Jquery Plugin in my demo file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue.
The combobox plugin is calling this line `document.body.innerHTML=_html;` when ever a select change is happening. What that does is replace the elements with clone of same elements but the problem here is it doesn't clone the events attached to it. (So i recommend not to use this plugin itself since it may kill other plugin events also).

To over come this you can use jQuery `delegated` event and it HAS TO BE assigned to `document` object or any parent object and use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

The updated code will look like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click',"#click-btn",function (){
        alert("jquery Work");
    });
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qq6uq7c6/25/) is a working fiddle.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer.I want to it.Continously,How to save changing class name when switch each option in dropdown listbox ?
My Project is here http://jsfiddle.net/qq6uq7c6/27/.Plz suggest !

Comment: save class name where?

Comment: i want to change unicode and zawgyi once time when switch each options in listbox.I want to save this changing class (unicode or zawgyi) in cookies by using jquery.

Comment: Yes, I has in comboBox.You will see setcookie and getcookie in this plugin.

Comment: your plugin is already storing the current font id so use `getcookie('leikpyar_converter_font')` to get the current font id

Comment: What wrong me? I want to save changing font and class name in cookies.
http://jsfiddle.net/qq6uq7c6/30/

Comment: cant you use the id for getting class name and font name?

Comment: Yes, U use font id for getting font and class name.

Comment: since the font data is from server side i cannot help you with that. also stackoverflow is NOT a site where you post requirements and get answers. You should try something on your own. Conclusion: try to use the id to get the font name and class.